# Break legend in two columns while keeping shape override

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a `ggplot` problem. Here is the example data:

```
df <- data.frame(x = rep(1:5,5),
                 type2 = c(rep(letters[1:2],each = 10),rep("c",5)),
                 type1 = rep(LETTERS[1:5],each = 5), 
                 value = unlist(lapply(-2:2,function(a){rnorm(5,mean = a, sd = 1)})))

library(ggplot2)

plotcolor <- c( "#99d8c9","#2ca25f","#cbc9e2","#9e9ac8","#e34a33")
p <- ggplot(df,aes(x,value,color = type1,fill = type1,shape = type2))+
  geom_point(size = 5)+
  theme_light()+
  labs(title =  "",
       color = "Method",
       fill = "Method",
       shape = "")+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0)+
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape =  c(21,21,24,24,22),
                                                   linetype = c(rep("blank",5)),
                                                   fill = plotcolor,
                                                   color = plotcolor)))+
  scale_shape(guide = FALSE)+
  scale_colour_manual(values = plotcolor)
p
```

which gives 
[image]

Now I want to split the legend into two columns, for space reasons. I tried

```
p + guides(color=guide_legend(ncol=2))
```

but it remove the `override` part of my legend, letting just points:

[image]

```
p + guides(color=guide_legend(ncol=2),
           fill =guide_legend(ncol=2) ,
           shape = guide_legend(ncol=2))
```

didn't work either. Does anyone have an idea on how to deal with this particular problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify `ncol` within the existing `guide_legend` (do not use it multiple times):

```
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = c(24,24,22,22,21),
                                                   linetype = c(rep("blank",5)),
                                                   fill = plotcolor,
                                                   color = plotcolor),
                               ncol = 2))+
```

[image]